# Log Log Integrals III

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form, zeta-functions

The integrals 
\begin{align}
I_{7} = \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x) \ \ln^{2}\left( \ln \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right) \ \frac{dx}{1-x}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
I_{8} = \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x) \ \ln^{2}\left( \ln \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right) \ \ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \ \frac{dx}{1-x}
\end{align}
can be expressed in terms of $\partial_{s}^{2}\zeta(s)|_{s=2}$ and $\partial_{s}^{2}\zeta(s)|_{s=3}$, respectively. Can these integrals be evaluated and provide a closed form expression without the use of derivatives of the Zeta function?

If the integrals can be evaluated in such a way what is the resulting value?

Comment: Aside: you could write $\zeta''(2)$ and $\zeta''(3)$ instead.

Comment: @Hurkyl this is true, but in a related problem proposed the notation you have stated gave some confusion. To remove this confusion the above, as stated in the problem, was used.